# What is the use of Zfill in this selenium code?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Could someone please explain what is the use of Zfill in the for loop while updating the index count?

While executing without the first Zfill that is with temp index I'm only able to scrape details about 3 job postings and then the for loop stops.
But while trying to execute it without the 2nd zfill that is with index I don't face any  noticeable issue.

Please help me resolve it.

```
Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(Path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# Update the URL of Naukri Page that you want to search ( Make Sure that the page link which you're putting must be a job listing page and it must have Next page buttons. )
driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/cyber-security-analyst-jobs?k=cyber%20security%20analyst")
count = 50  # it's the Number of Vacancy count you want to scrape.
index, new_index, i = '0', 1, 0   # This the the index variable of the elements from which data will be Scraped
# Xpaths of the various element from which data will be scraped.
title_xpath = '(//*[@class="jobTuple bgWhite br4 mb-8"])['+index+']/div/div/a'
link_xpath = '(//*[@class="jobTuple bgWhite br4 mb-8"])['+index+']/div/div/a'
comp_xpath = '(//*[@class="jobTuple bgWhite br4 mb-8"])['+index+']/div/div/div/a'
exp_xpath = '(//*[@class="jobTuple bgWhite br4 mb-8"])['+index+']/div/div/ul/li[1]/span'
salary_xpath = '(//*[@class="jobTuple bgWhite br4 mb-8"])['+index+']/div/div/ul/li[2]/span'

# the file name the of CSV file.
csv_file = open('Naukri_scrape.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Company Name', 'Vacancy Link', 'Experience Needed', 'Salary'])

while i < count:

    for j in range(20):#no of jobs in a page is always 20 or less than 20

        # Here we're replacing the Old index count of Xpath with temp Index count.
        temp_index = str(new_index).zfill(2)
        title_xpath = title_xpath.replace(index, temp_index)
        link_xpath = link_xpath.replace(index, temp_index)
        comp_xpath = comp_xpath.replace(index, temp_index)
        exp_xpath = exp_xpath.replace(index, temp_index)
        salary_xpath = salary_xpath.replace(index, temp_index)
        index = str(new_index).zfill(2)
        try:     
            heading = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, title_xpath))).text
            print(heading)
        except:
            heading = "Not Available"
        try:
            link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, link_xpath))).get_attribute('href')
            print(link)
        except:
            link = "Not Available"
        try:
            subheading = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, comp_xpath))).text
            print(subheading)
        except:
            subheading = "NULL"
        try:
            experience = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, exp_xpath))).text
            print(experience)
        except:
            experience = "Not Available"
        try:
            salary = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, salary_xpath))).text
            print(salary)
        except:
            salary = "Not Disclosed"
        new_index += 1
        i += 1
        print(str(i)+".")
       # Writing all the Scrapped data into CSV file.
        csv_writer.writerow([heading, subheading, link, experience, salary])
        if i >= count:
            break
    if i >= count:
        break
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "Next"]'))).click()
    new_index = 1
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Did you look for the documentation for `zfill`?  If not, please do it, and if you have a question after that, please be *specific* about what it is exactly that you don't understand.

Comment: Yes I do understand the use of Zfill, I just want to know why have they use Zfill in this code while updating index values? What difference does it make? Also is there any alternatives instead of using zfill in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The use of zfill here makes no sense. It is not a way to increment a loop index. I can't tell you why the code is there, but it is superfluous at best.

Let's simplify this.  Those xpaths are WAY too complicated. There are far better CSS selectors you may use. Here's an example I might start with:

```
title_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.title.fw500.ellipsis')
```

This returns an array containing all of the job titles on the page, however many there may be. Then, `link_elements = title_elements` should work; the xpaths defined in your example are the same for these anyway.

You may then find an array of all of the company elements utilizing the CSS Selector `'div.companyInfo > a.subTitle'`. for salary: `'li.salary > span'`. A similar selector works to find all of the experience elements, too: `'li.experience > span'`

It is then straightforward to loop through the arrays and obtain the data you want to scrape. This should be, say, 12 lines of code in total!